# Has c++ standard specified the evaluation order of an operator&&(built-in)?

Tags: c++, logical-operators, operator-precedence, expression-evaluation

I always dare NOT to code like this:

```
void func( some_struct* ptr ) {
    if ( ptr != nullptr && ptr->errorno == 0 )
        do something...
};
```

instead I always do like this:

```
void func( some_struct* ptr ) {
    if ( ptr != nullptr )
        if ( ptr->errorno == 0 )
            do something...
};
```

because I'm afraid that the evaluation order of logical operator && is un-specified in C++ standard, even though commonly we could get right results with almost all of nowdays compilers.
In [a book](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm), 2 rules let me want to get known exactly about it.

My question is :
Without overloading,  is the evaluation order of logical operator "&&" and "||" definite?

Sorry about my ugly English, I'm a Chinese. and I apologize if there is a duplicated topic, because I can't finger out correct key-words to search with.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's guaranteed for built-in logical AND operator and logical OR operator by the standard.

(emphasis mine)

[[expr.log.and]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.log.and#1)

> The && operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both [contextually converted to bool](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv#def:conversion,contextual_to_bool). The result is `true` if both operands are `true` and `false` otherwise. Unlike &, **&& guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is `false`**.

[[expr.log.or]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.log.or#1)

> The || operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both [contextually converted to bool](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/conv#def:conversion,contextual_to_bool). The result is `true` if either of its operands is `true`, and `false` otherwise. Unlike |, **|| guarantees left-to-right evaluation; moreover, the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand evaluates to `true`**.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluation order for `&&` and `||` is left to right.

Means in this case `if (condition-1 && condition-2)`, then compiler will first check condition-1. If condition-1 is true then it will go to check next condition. But if condition-1 if false. It will return false as in `&&` one false condition means result is false

Sameway in case of `if (condition-1 || condition-2)`, compiler will first check condition-1. If it is true then it will return true. Because if `||`, if one condition is true, then result is true. No need to check next conditions. But if it is false it will check next condition...

Comment: I know, I meant to say that the short-circuiting operators check conditions from left-to-right and not right-to-left. As can be seen here [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cpp-built-in-operators-precedence-and-associativity?view=vs-2019)

Comment: The term "evaluation order" covers that, and it's in the question. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Is this correct now?

Comment: Yes that is now correct, although "*No need to check next conditions.*" still makes it sound as if that was a sufficient condition for the short-circuiting rule to apply e.g. also for other operators, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Those operators have fixed evaluation rules that you can rely on.

You can safely use code like this:

```
if (op1 && op2)
```

With `&&`, both operands are needed to result to `true` in order for it to be `true`, if one of them is `false` then it *short circuits*, meaning that further evaluation of the `&&` stops and it returns `false`. In short words, if the first operand is `false` then the second operand will not be evaluated since the operator will return `false` immediately.

For the case of `||` it will short circuit if *at least* one of its operands its true. Therefore, if the first operand is `true` then it will not evaluate the second operand because the operator returns `true` automatically.

This means that code like this: `if (op1 && op2)` is equivalent to:

```
if (op1)
{
    if (op2)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

And code like this `if (op1 || op2)` is the same as:

```
if (op1)
{
    //some code
}
else if (op2)
{
    //same code
}
```

Check these to know more about [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and [logical operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical).

Comment: "*the evaluation order is well defined.*": That seems wrong or misleading. In most cases the evaluation order of operands is *not* specified in C++.

Comment: "*For any deterministic language, such as C++, the evaluation order is well defined.*" -- That's not true in general. Even in C++, the evaluation order of the operands of *most* operators is *not* well defined. The `&&` and `||` operators happen to be a special case, and the order of operation and short-circuit semantics are guaranteed only because the language explicitly says so.

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz For most operators the deterministic rule is that the evaluation order is unspecified (indeterministic), so that is a misleading way to talk about it, see also the first sentence in your links: "*Order of evaluation of any part of any expression, including order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified (with some exceptions listed below).*" A program could randomly give different results for expressions that behave differently depending on the evaluation order.

Comment: `&&` and `||` are the exceptions. Replace them with `&` or `|` and `a` and `b` by compound expressions and the result may be either of multiple possibilities.

Comment: `int f() { static int i=0; return i++; } int main() { std::cout << f()-f(); }` The program can print either `1` or `-1`. In practice a compiler will of course choose either one of the orders and deterministically stick with it, but the standard does not require that.

Comment: @uneven_mark now I'm certain I was confusing the compiler implementation and the language specs. Thanks. By the way, I got `-1` in VS, Intel++ and GCC-arm, in which have you got `1`?

Comment: @JavierSilvaOrtíz I have not tested it and I don't know whether any current compiler does print `1`, but the point is that the compilers are free to decide without informing you. E.g. if the calculation in `f` would be more complicated, the optimizer may decide that evaluation in a certain order is faster and choose that or it might not. You cannot rely on the result that any particular (or many particular) compiler (version) is giving you.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/yABJN8) is a variation where I know that GCC and Clang differ in behavior.